# Reselect's Selector with Props after Unmounting

Tags: react-redux, reselect

The example code for creating a selector that uses the props is as follows:

```
const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getVisibleTodos = makeGetVisibleTodos()
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props)
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}

connect(makeMapStateToProps)(Component);
```

However, this means the memoized selectors will be lost after the component gets unmounted (unlike the selectors defined in a file).

Is there a way in Reselect library to save these selectors?

If not, what would be the best approach of saving them? I am thinking of caching, but I would need one selector for every value.